# Laravel 5.7 creating cache files with 'or' instead of?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm currently using laravel 5.7 and the files automaticaly created by laravel in the /storage/views contain some code with 'or' instead of ?? which is no longer supported.

I was wondering what can be done to fix this, because I don't want to have to modify the code manually everytime the cache is cleared.
composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "4.0",
        "graham-campbell/flysystem": "^5.0",
        "hivokas/laravel-passport-social-grant": "^1.1",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.3",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.1",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.1",
        "league/flysystem": "^1.0",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.3",
        "monarobase/country-list": "^2.1",
        "usmanhalalit/laracsv": "1.*@dev",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "laravel/dusk": "^5.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "DarSiHmad\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

file created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        @media  only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .inner-body {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .footer {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media  only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .button {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <?php echo e($header or ''); ?>


                    <!-- Email Body -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <!-- Body content -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="content-cell">
                                        <?php echo e(Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot)); ?>


                                        <?php echo e($subcopy or ''); ?>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php echo e($footer or ''); ?>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As of php 8.0, the operator `or` is still supported (and will always be AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

found my problem,
instead of playing with versions I modified the code directly in resources/views/vendor/email/html/layout.blade.php
to contain ?? instead of 'or'.
now the cache files are created with valid code with laravel 5.7